# Intellisense not showing exceptions in vs2008 C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, intellisense

The intellsiense in my vs 2008 does not show the exceptions that might be drawn when im using a function. writing in C# 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking for exceptions that could be thrown by your code, I don't believe Visual Studio does this natively. There are, however, products that do show you potential exceptions, like [Red-Gate's Exception Hunter](http://www.red-gate.com/products/Exception_Hunter/index.htm). They have a free 15-day trial so you can see if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: If you document your functions like this
/// <summary>
/// Dinosaur gets bigger, by eating a big mammoth.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="MeteorFellOnMeException"></exception>
public void GetBigger()

You will get the exception description by intellisense, however when hovering on a BCL func like SqlConnection.Open() you get nothing.